# In JavaScript how to have a readonly textarea and still get onselect events?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have noticed that if I set a textarea to 'readonly'
I no longer get `onselect` events.

```
var ta = document.createElement('textarea');
ta.readonly = true;
ta.onselect = function() { ... } // This one works only if the ta.readonly is commented out.
```

I need the textarea to be readonly and be notified when the user selects a certain range.
Can somebody help?

Comment: You can still handle events from a readOnly field- as long as it is not disabled. Tabbing to it will fire its focus event, away will call its blur, and selecting works normally. The only change to a normal field is the user cannot change its value.

Comment: that's not true. I tried that both in chrome and firefox. my textarea is enabled and readonly but onselect never gets called when I do my own selections.

Comment: Does the textarea need to have the readonly attribute only to make sure users can't edit it? Also, do users need to be able to copy/paste any of the selection in the textarea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no straightforward way to do this by dynamically adjusting the textarea's readonly attribute onfocus, onblur, onselect, etc. while still always receiving the onselect event.

If your goal is to make sure that users cannot edit/manipulate the textarea, then I would probably just leave the textarea as non-readonly (to receive the select events) but block all user input inside of it by using preventDefault() on input events, like so:

```
var ta = document.createElement('textarea');

// prevent user input
ta.addEventListener('cut', function(e) { e.preventDefault(); }, false);
ta.addEventListener('copy', function(e) { e.preventDefault(); }, false);
ta.addEventListener('paste', function(e) { e.preventDefault(); }, false);
ta.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) { e.preventDefault(); }, false);

// listen for user selections
ta.addEventListener('select', function() {
    // function logic...
}, false);
```

Comment: Thank you. I had to add the following line to your list:



`ta.addEventListener('dragstart', function(e) { e.preventDefault(); }, false);`



That aside your trick works for me.

Answer (score 0):

How about just using a `<div>`? You can still select text in there, and it'll be non-editable, hence readonly.

Comment: You won't get `select` events from it though.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a loop function that keeps checking for window text selection. If it detects that the length of the select text has reached some sort of limit it will execute what ever you see fit.

Something like this:

```
function getSelectedText() {
    var txt = '';
    if (window.getSelection) {
        txt = window.getSelection();
    } 
    else if (document.getSelection) // FireFox
    {
        txt = document.getSelection();
    }
    else if (document.selection)  // IE 6/7
    {
        txt = document.selection.createRange().text;
    }
    return txt;
}
function doSomething() {
    var txt = getSelectedText();
    // Do something with txt variable, like txt.length
}
setInterval('doSomething()',500);
```

You would also need to make sure the selection is from the desired textarea.

Hopefully this will point you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks. interesting answer. I still wonder if there is something less compicated.

Comment: I suggest adding something like a button that will fire the getSelectedText() rather than using setInterval() which will slow down your application and also the client's computer.

Comment: Yes, that's true. But it should not have that big of an impact.